# Mathematica: Having a plot inside a loop of a module updated

Tags: dynamic, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to have a module like this

```
TestModule[n_] := Module[{{dataList = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}}}},
 For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
 Pause[0.5];
 Print[ ListLinePlot[dataList++]];
 ];
];
```

where a the values of a list get updated from iteration to iteration and instead of having the module producing me n plots, I rather would like to have only one plot, which is updated  n times after each iteration.

I looked already at Dynamics[] and Monitor[], but could not yet find a solution with them. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Ok, I already got it:
    TestModule[n_] := Module[{dataList = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}}, i},
   Print[Dynamic[
     ListLinePlot[dataList]]];
   For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    Pause[0.5];
    dataList = dataList + 1;
    ];
   ];

Comment: Why don't you use `Manipulate` ?

Answer (score 1):

here is a straightforward application of `Monitor`:

```
TestModule[n_] := Module[{
    dataList = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}},
    plot = "starting..."
  },
  Monitor[
    Do[
      Pause[0.5];
      plot = ListLinePlot[dataList++, PlotRange -> {0, n + 2}],
      {i, 1, n}
    ],
    plot
  ];
  plot
];
```

Do you know [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)? You'll get much more answers for Mathematica specific questions there...